# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 'date datatype error'

Tags: oracle10g

```
create table Coordinate_with
(
  cor_id char(6),
  cmp_id char(6),
  start_date date,      
  shifted varchar(10),  
  primary key (cor_id,cmp_id),
  foreign key (cor_id) references Coordinator(cor_id),
  foreign key (cmp_id) references Company(cmp_id)
);

insert into Coordinate_with
values ('COR-01','CMP-02','2009-03-22','Morning');
```

Throwing Error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Literal does not match format string in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152955/literal-does-not-match-format-string-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you supply a "plain" string the value is converted using implicit type conversion based on your NLS setting. A (standard) date literal needs the keyword `date` followed by a string formatted in ISO style (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
insert into Coordinate_with 
  (cor_id, cmp_id, start_date, shifted)
values 
  ('COR-01','CMP-02', DATE '2009-03-22','Morning');
```

Alternatively you can use the `to_date()` function:

```
insert into Coordinate_with 
  (cor_id, cmp_id, start_date, shifted)
values 
  ('COR-01','CMP-02', to_date('2009-03-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd','Morning');
```

<sup>Btw: `work_shift` might have been a better column name for `shifted`. I told you, that you will need to find a name that matches what the column contains.</sup>

Comment: @user2326894: I think you should *really* start reading the Oracle manual.

Comment: I jus started sql few days bck...
I will surely start reading the manual...
Thnks for support